# Unable to see resources as directories Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

in alot of online tutorials I can see that one can navigate through resources in azure as if it were a directory.

When I use Cloud Shell this feature is not available to me.

I only have following directory structure.

```
Directory: /home/MY NAME  


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
l----           6/19/2020  6:08 AM                clouddrive -> /usr/csuser/clouddrive
```

Does anybody know what I am missing?

regards
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

It's expected behavior.

Azure Cloud Shell runs on a temporary host and is assigned one machine per user account. Cloud Shell persists `$HOME` using a 5-GB image held in your file share. By default, you have full permission to access the `/home/user` directory. Additionally, your `$HOME` directory is persisted as an `.img` in your Azure File share. Files outside of `$HOME` and machine state are not persisted across sessions.

Read [Overview of Azure Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview#features) for more details.

[image]